# Grep with multiple keywords and output multiple lines

Tags: linux, grep

I want to grep lines contains all 3 different patterns, and output them with 2 previous lines and 1 next line.

This is the command I could grep without multiple line output. Now I want to add 3 additional line mentioned above. Can I put -A and -B together? Or do I have to use -C? Where should I put those options, all in three conditions or first or last?

```
grep -e Melon -e Banana -e Lemon *txt | grep Tomato | grep Milk
```

This is sample input

```
Egg Tomato    
Salad Coffee
Melon Tomato Milk
Noodle Salmon
Banana Potato Milk
Salmon Rice
```

Expected output is

```
Egg Tomato 
Salad Coffee
Melon Tomato Milk
Noodle Salmon
```

Comment: Please include example `input` and `expected` data

Comment: @ Jose Ricardo Bustos M. I added input and expected output

Comment: why isn't `Banana Potato Milk` in the expected output? Also, what is the logic here? You want lines containing either of Melon, Banan and Lemon or all of them?

Comment: because of "grep Tomato". The command I am trying to write is "(Melon or Banana or Lemon) and Tomato and Milk" Both Tomato and Milk has to be in the line.

Comment: `grep -A1 -B2 -E -e "(Tomato.*Milk|Milk.*Tomato).*(Melon|Banana|Lemon)" -e "(Melon|Banana|Lemon).*(Tomato.*Milk|Milk.*Tomato)" -e "Tomato.*(Melon|Banana|Lemon).*Milk" -e "Milk.*(Melon|Banana|Lemon).*Tomato" *txt` I don't know if it can be improved

Comment: It says "*" is invalid for the command. Is there something I have to add to use Regex?

Comment: `-E` option, Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A large solution, you want: Two lines above and one line below of pattern: `(Melon or Banana or Lemon) and Tomato and Milk`

```
grep -A1 -B2 -E -e "(Tomato.*Milk|Milk.*Tomato).*(Melon|Banana|Lemon)" \
                -e "(Melon|Banana|Lemon).*(Tomato.*Milk|Milk.*Tomato)" \
                -e "Tomato.*(Melon|Banana|Lemon).*Milk" \
                -e "Milk.*(Melon|Banana|Lemon).*Tomato" *txt
```

**Only for fun**

Another solution using `awk`

```
awk '
    flag{print; flag=0}
    /Melon|Banana|Lemon/ && /Milk/ && /Tomato/{
        printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n",prev[0],prev[1],$0
        flag=1; next
    }
    {prev[0]=prev[1]; prev[1]=$0}' *txt
```

Comment: Yes I could grep exactly what I wanted!! Thank you very much for your help. I thought there would be some easy way but seems not.